# My client is requesting many times the same ajax on every click. How can i prevent that?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am creating a portal that uses three different ajax, triggered by clicking at the links of an autogenerated menu.

The problem is that, as i click at the many links of the menu, my browser takes more time and more memory to take those requests.

My problem is very clear in the network tab of the development tools in chrome.

The first time i click, i get only one request for every ajax page, but the second time i have two requests of the identical ajax pages.
The third time 4 requests, then 8, then 16, then 32 and so on.

How could i prevent that?

This is the code of my javascript page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var ajaxser;
var ajaxfun1;
var ajaxfun2;


$("a.servicelink").one("click",function () {

    $("#ajaxloader").show();


    var select = $(this).attr("ser:id");


    ajaxser = $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/ajaxservicetab.php",
        type: 'post',
        data: {'select': select},
        success: function (data)
        {
            var servicetable = data;
            $("#content").html(servicetable);


            ajaxfun1 = $.ajax({
                url: "ajax/ajaxfunctionmenu.php",
                type: 'post',
                data: {'select': select},
                success: function (data)
                {
                    var functionmenu = data;
                    $("#functionality").html(functionmenu);
                    $("#ajaxloader").hide();
                }
            });
        }

    });



$("a.servicelink").unbind();     

});
$("a.functionlink").click(function () {
    $("#ajaxloader").show();



    var funid = $(this).attr("fun:id");
    var appid = $(this).attr("app:id");
    var funnome = $(this).attr("nom:id");

    ajaxfun2 = $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/ajaxfunctiontab.php",
        type: 'post',
        data: {'funid': funid, 'appid': appid, 'funnome': funnome},
        success: function (data)
        {
            var functiontable = data;
            $("#content").html(functiontable);

            $("#ajaxloader").hide();

        },
        complete: function () {
            $("a.servicelink").unbind(); 
            $("a.servicelink").off(); 
            ajaxser.abort();
        }
    });

$("a.functionlink").unbind(); 

});
```

EDIT:

By clicking to "a.servicelink" i call two ajax: ajaxser and ajaxfun1.

The ajax page called with ajaxfun1 contains "a.functionlink" that calls ajaxfun2.

EDIT2:

I edited the code by adding the unbind functionality.
What changes is that on the second click the ajax is called just one time, but on the third it's called again two times, then 4 and so on.

EDIT3: Added the "complete" method, no differences. Code updated.

Comment: Sounds like on every click you somehow rebind all the events.

Comment: try .. `.unbind( "click" )`

Comment: @  epascarello Yes, but the "ser:id" value in them is always the last one.

Comment: @ Punit Gajjar. Where?

Comment: You can also try  $(this).unbind();  after ajax call  for example `$("#element").bind("click",function(){
    //do stuff here
    $(this).unbind();
}`

Comment: I updated the code but the unbind function doesn't change much.
Still i edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add a complete method.

```
complete: function() {
        // Disable (a.servicelink) click event here and re-enable after callback.
}
```

Comment: I added:

complete: function () {
                $("a.servicelink").unbind(); 
                $("a.servicelink").off(); 
                ajaxser.abort();
            }

But that doesn't change anything.
Is there something i missed?